# Careers: Technologies field should auto-scroll or expand

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When you are filling out your CV in Careers, under the Experience section, the Technologies field states to "list up to 10 core technologies you used..."

However, once you enter more than a few, the entries end up being longer than the text field, and the cursor isn't automatically placed at the end of the text field as you add more entries.

For example, I was attempting to enter "nunit" as my sixth or so core technology, so I typed its first few letters and then hit enter as soon as the auto-complete recognized it. However, instead of seeing "nunit" on the text box, it didn't auto-scroll, and so I saw "nun". I had to click on the text field and hit End to see the entire tag. This would be much more pronounced for longer tags.

Comment: `nun`? I didn't know catholic priestesses were technology =D