# Careers 2.0 - Technologies length

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, user-interface, user-experience

Besides the [inconvenient UI for inputing technologies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27395/careers-technologies-field-should-auto-scroll-or-expand),
a limit of 100 characters for listing 10 technologies, where many technologies are way over 10 characters + 1 space is a problem.

Also, for education or experience with a duration of a few years, 10 technologies is simply not enough.

Is it possible to provide a multi-line input control without the 100 character limit, with a limit of about 5 technologies per year of duration?

Comment: I +1 because of the 100 chars limit. I have an entry where I used to have 10 techs. Today I noticed a mistake and wanted to make it more relevant, and I remove 2 techs in there... and I cannot re-add them because the combined length of the 8 previous keywords is more than 100 chars. Bummer that changed in-between :)

Comment: @Nick three years passed, is this still planned?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You have no idea how planned this is.

Comment: @Jason hey, how did you notice the comment? ;)

Comment: Wasn't this implemented already? - The limitation seems to have changed.

Comment: @Danny cool, didn't check it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is biting me right now. For education, I have: "software-engineering design uml project-management communication team configuration-management software-quality". That's only 8 tags. I would love to be able to change "design" to "design-patterns" and add at least one more tag. Unfortunately, I can't. This has been planned since April. Any word on updates?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was already changed at some point - it seems you can type as much as you want into the Technologies box now. Something like only the first 300 characters are displayed on your profile, but that ought to be enough for anybody...