# Remove limit of characters when editing the StackCareers profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers 2.0 - Technologies length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87825/careers-2-0-technologies-length)

I'm editing my StackCareers profile, and in *Technologies*, under the *Education* tab, it says:

[image: example]

but that field only allows a maximum of `100` characters.

**Shouldn't that restriction be removed (or increased) and just validate against the number of technologies entered?**

**Edit:**
I added the **Bug** tag because if you're out of characters in that field, but start writing, for example, `discrete-mat`, a pop-up will appear suggesting you to select `discrete-mathematics`, and if you select it, the field will have more than 100 characters.

I don't know if something similar could occur in some other place of any SE site, but if I find it, I will just post a new question to report the bug. Of course, unless this is not a bug and is the desired behaviour...