# Technologies field is limited by length and not just by number of tags

Tags: bug, tags, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers 2.0 - Technologies length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87825/careers-2-0-technologies-length)

When adding tags to a technologies used field for an experience section, the amount of tags you can enter is also constrained by the total number of characters.

The description says that you are allowed to add 10 tags, however there is also a 100 character hard limit that can prevent you from adding tags. Considering there are plenty of tags that are more than 10 characters this means you might not be able to use all of them. It would be more logical that the character hard limit is removed for this field.

Here is a sample that will break, and is only 9 tags:

```
active-directory jqueryui asp.net-mvc nhibernate castle-windsor sql-server cryptography wcf javascript
```

Comment: strange, i did a lot of searches but did not find the duplicate question. sorry about the dupe.